# Read and write using fgetcsv and fputcsv

Tags: php, csv, fgetcsv, fputcsv

I have a 3rd party source from where I am getting "csv" file. I wrote it inside a quote because it says it's a csv file but basically it's not.

So I am taking that main source file then reading and putting the data in a "PROPER" csv file.

The read and write is fine but the problem is when it saves the properly quoted data is writing on the script file itself.For example if the my php file name is "fixcsv.php" then I am getting the downloadable file as  "fixcsv.php".

My code

```
$headings = array('HID');
$handle = fopen("MonC1.csv", "r");
$data = fgetcsv($handle, 0, ";",'"');
$fh = fopen('php://output', 'w');
ob_start();
fputcsv($fh, $headings);
// Loop over the * to export
if (! empty($data)) {
  foreach ($data as $item) {
     // echo $item;
     fputcsv($fh, array($item));
  }
}
$string = ob_get_clean();

$filename = 'csv_' . date('Ymd') .'_' . date('His');

// Output CSV-specific headers
header("Pragma: public");
header("Expires: 0");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Cache-Control: private",false);
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment filename=\"$filename.csv\";" );
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");

exit($string);
```

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Content-Disposition` has a semi-colon in the wrong place ([per the spec](http://www.servlets.com/rfcs/rfc2616-sec19.html#sec19.5.1)).  Should be:

```
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$filename.csv\" );
```

Comment: Thanks but it still giving me the scriptname to save the file

Comment: Flush your browser cache?  (I realize that's what `Cache-Control: private` is supposed to do, but nevertheless...)

Comment: Cleared the cache but still no luck.Have no clue why it is prompting me to save the script file.

Comment: It worked the problem was in the filename. Thanks a lot.